# Java based GUI scrolling is buggy in Linux VM

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swing

I just downloaded the new Neon Eclipse for C++ dev (4.6.0) and updated my Linux machine to use Java 1.8.0_91. I noticed once I started using the program that the scrolling is terribly inertial such that if you flick downwards the pane will scroll for ~15s before stopping.

At first I thought it was an issue with Eclipse but then I used git merge tool and observed the same problem. My friend says it is probably an issue with "Swing". Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It certainly isn't Swing because Eclipse doesn't use it (it uses SWT).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is an issue with GTK3? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434898